# Generating a list of unique dates across multiple columns

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I will explain in detail so it is clear what I am trying to do. My question at the end will be if there is an easier way to do it.

I need to create a list of all the different dates which are listed across 6 different date fields (columns). It doesnt matter how many times the dates occur, i just need to identify that on that date something happened.

To do this, have run six different queries which go to each column and Group the results and paste them to another column in a holding table.  After doing this accross all six fields pasting them all to the same holidng table, i then take the holding table and Group the results to get a complete listing of every date which occurred.

I was wondering if there is an easier way to do this or some type of VBA function which surveys the six columns and produces an exaustive list of all the items it encounters.

Hope my explanation wasn't too confusing.
A

Answer (score 2):

If you have a table named [MyTable] with six (6) `Date/Time` fields...

```
ID  DateA       DateB       DateC       DateD       DateE       DateF     
--  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
 1  2014-01-01  2014-01-02  2014-01-03  2014-01-04  2014-01-05  2014-01-06
 2  2014-01-02  2014-01-03  2014-01-04  2014-01-05  2014-01-06  2014-01-07
```

...then you can get a list of unique dates from all six fields with a simple UNION query

```sql
SELECT DateA AS DateValue FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT DateB AS DateValue FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT DateC AS DateValue FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT DateD AS DateValue FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT DateE AS DateValue FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT DateF AS DateValue FROM MyTable
```

returning

```
DateValue 
----------
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
2014-01-04
2014-01-05
2014-01-06
2014-01-07
```

Comment: Thanks Gord..  I dont understand however two things..  How do i link this to my table with the long column full of dates ranging from 2010 to the present..   Also, why 6 columns ?